# Grails: specifying classpath for hsqldb

Tags: oracle, grails, grails-orm, hsqldb

In our project we use Grails as Web-framework, Oracle db for deployment and HSQLDB for development and testing. Some queries use Oracle specific functions such as TRUNC or TO_DATE, unfortunately, HSQLDB does not have support for them. So this means that that we could not create integration tests without some pre-work.

HSQLDB has support for stored functions written in Java, so I'm going to mimic TRUNC and TO_DATE by writing stored java functions. For example, TRUNC could be defined like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TRUNC(v DOUBLE) RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE JAVA DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:java.lang.Math.floor'
```

And this works. Because standard java class Math is on the HSQLDB server's classpath. For, to_date function there is no standard java function, so I need to write my own. No problem, say it's called - to_date and located in com.stackoverflow.HSQLDBOracleSupport class. When I should run such query

```
CREATE FUNCTION TO_DATE(d VARCHAR, format VARCHAR) RETURNS DATE
LANGUAGE JAVA DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:com.stackoverflow.HSQLDBOracleSupport.to_date'
```

The problem is that I don't know, where should I place my HSQLDBOracleSupport.class. Documentation says that it should be "on hsqldb server's classpath". But which classpath is used? How can I configure DataSource in Grails in order to specify hsqldb classpath?

Comment: The latest HSQLDB 2.2.5 supports both TRUNC and TO_DATE functions.